# QueryRecord processor to perform aggregate SQL function in NiFi

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi

I have the followimg flow :

**QueryDatabaseTable ->QueryRecord -> UpdateAttribute->MergeContent->PutelasticsearchHttp**

The idea is to fetch the records from database and perform aggregate functions on the fields. In my database Table i have following 4 fields :

```
DeptId  DepartmentName  Address  ExperienNo

1    DS    San Jose      4

2    GT    San Fran      6

3    At    Oakland       8

4    BMS   detroit       3

5    RT    Haawai        9
```

and I have set the controller services for QueryREcord as Avroreader and CSVSetWritter with following as schema:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "SQLSchema",
"fields" : [
{"name": "DeptId", "type": "int"},
{"name": "DepartmentName", "type": "string"},
{"name": "Address", "type": "string"},
{"name": "ExperienceNo", "type": "int"},
{"name": "Total_Experience", "type": "int"}
]
}
```

I want to perform the difference on two fields (DeptId-ExperienceNo)

**My SQL query is as follow:**

```
SELECT DeptId, DepartmentName,Address,ExperienceNo,
(DeptId - ExperienceNo) AS Total_Experience FROM flowfile
```

I get `error as 'Total_Experience' cannot be null`.

However the same query runs fine in MySQL. How can this be achieved, where I can perform SQL aggregate function on fields and alias that as a new **dynamic** column.

Thank you.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **csv reader** controller service is configured with

`{"name": "Total_Experience", "type": "int"}` field with out default value and in your **input data** you are not getting this field.

So processor is **complaining** `Total_Experience` cannot be `null`.

To fix this issue change the **avro schema** to include **null** value for **Total_Experience** field.

> **Avro Schema:**

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "SQLSchema",
"fields" : [
{"name": "DeptId", "type": "int"},
{"name": "DepartmentName", "type": "string"},
{"name": "Address", "type": "string"},
{"name": "ExperienceNo", "type": "int"},
{"name": "Total_Experience", "type": ["null","int"]}
]
}
```

**CsvReader Controller service Configs:**

[image]

**Output:**

```
DeptId,DepartmentName,Address,ExperienceNo,Total_Experience
1,DS,San Jose,4,-3
2,GT,San Fran,6,-4
3,At,Oakland,8,-5
4,BMS,detroit,3,1
5,RT,Haawai,9,-4
```

**Correct way of doing this would be:**

Configuring **CSV Reader** without **Total_Experience** field and
Include **Total_Experience** in **CsvSetWriter** controller service as you are creating this field by `using Query record` processor.